# What is "the space consisting of two stacked torus surfaces, stacked as one would stack two inner tubes"?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-topology

This is a question in Fraleigh's abstract algebra book asking for computing the homology groups of this shape. But I do not understand that sentence and English is not my mother language...

Could someone please explain to me what is "stacked as one would stack two inner tubes"?

Comment: I don't have the book on me, but it sounds like what would happen if you stacked two donuts on top of each other. Then, the two tori intersect in a circle.

Comment: Two tori  contacting on their flat circles

Comment: @TakumiMurayama  thanks for comment, now I can understand that sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this. ${}{}{}{}$

[image]

Comment: It's kind of an interesting space topologically.  What is it's fundamental group?  I'm guessing $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$?

Comment: The space is homeomorphic to $(S^1\vee S^1)\times S^1$, so it's fundamental group is $(\Bbb Z*\Bbb Z)\times \Bbb Z$.

Comment: @iwriteonbananas Is $\Bbb Z * \Bbb Z$ the free group on two generators?

Comment: Indeed it is, @GregoryGrant.

Comment: @iwriteonbananas I see.  Thank you.  So I stand by my original contention.  This is an interesting space.  :-)

Comment: Sure it is, @GregoryGrant :)